# Access register who's number is stored in another register

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

I am working on a project for one of my classes which involves translating C code into MIPS assembly. I am having trouble translating this code:

```
r[extract(ir,15,11)] = aluout;
```

Basically, r[] is an array which represents the registers in C. As you can see, it determines which register to access based on the result from the `extract` function. Is there anything like this in MIPS? The only way I can think to do it is to take the value that I will get back from the extract subroutine and check it against all register numbers. The C representation of this would look like:

```
regNum = extract(ir, 15, 11);
if (regNum == 1) {
    r[1] = aluout;
} else if (regNum == 2) {
    r[2] = aluout;
} else if (regNum == 3) {
    r[3] = aluout;
} ...
```

Any ideas? Is this the only way to go about it?

Comment: Umm, you can index an array. You can't index the raw registers though.

Comment: Yeah I know. The C code is something our professor gave us that we are supposed to translate into MIPS. r[index] just represents the register $[index] if you were to translate it to MIPS

Comment: So you're writing a MIPS assembly program that's supposed to emulate a (MIPS?) CPU. I'd just keep the emulated registers in an array like you would with C. You probably can't keep all the emulated registers in real registers because you'll need some real registers for something else in your program.

Comment: Instead of checking all numbers, you could use a jump table; have all 32 possible instructions somewhere and jump to the right one.  You could also do it with self-modifying code, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you supposed to use self-modifying code?  e.g. put the register-number into an instruction that's about to run?

The problem is more analogous to having multiple named variables in C (`var1`, `var2`, etc.) and having to return the value in var `i`.  You can do it with the preprocessor if `i` is a compile-time constant:

```
#define expandvar(x) var ## x   // two step process to macro-expand x before concat
#define var(x) expandvar(x)
#define wantvar  4

int foo(void) { return var(wantvar); }
// int foo(constexpr int i) { ... }  // nope
```

Otherwise you need a `switch()` which you can implement however you want (jump table, branch tree, or whatever.)

There's no level of indirection for registers, unless you store them all to memory and then use a variable offset into that array.

One way to implement this is with a calculated jump, rather than with a table of jump addresses.  You'd have a sequence of

```
# calculate $t0 = set_r0 + reg_num * 8.  (probably using PC as the starting point, rather than actually referencing the address of set_r0)
j $t0     # jump to one of the pairs.

set_r0:
    move $r0, src
    j end
    move $r1, src
    j end
    ...
```

If you wanted to retrieve the value of one register, but clobber all the others,

```
    move $r30, $r31
    move $r29, $r30
    move $r28, $r29
    ...
    move $r0, $r1
```

jump into this at the point where the reg you want is read.